# Unity: Javascript callbacks, delegates

Tags: callback, delegates, unity-game-engine, unityscript, player.io

I would like to use Player.IO from Yahoo Games Network in my Unity javascript code. PlayerIO provides example project for unity written only in C# so I am having problems with getting the callbacks work.

`PlayerIO.Connect` description from Player.IO documentation for Unity ([available here](https://gamesnet.yahoo.com/documentation/reference/unity3d/playerioclient.playerio#Connect)):

```
public void Connect (string gameId, string connectionId, string userId, string auth,
string partnerId, String[] playerInsightSegments,
Callback<Client> successCallback, Callback<PlayerIOError> errorCallback)
```

### **So how to make these callbacks work?**

*The following part of the question shows the ways I have already tried, but didn't work.*

---

Firstly I've tried this way (as I know from javascript):

```
function success(client : Client) {
  //function content
}
PlayerIOClient.PlayerIO.Connect(pioGameId, pioConnectionId, pioUserId, pioAuth, pioPartnerId, success, failed);
```

.

---

That was not right and I've learned that I should use delegates.
From Unity3D official tutorials ([available here](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/scripting/delegates)), the right use of delegates in JS would be like this (using the `Function` type):

```
var successDelegate : Function;

function success(client : Client) {
  //function content
}

function Start () {
    successDelegate = success;
    PlayerIOClient.PlayerIO.Connect(pioGameId, pioConnectionId, pioUserId, pioAuth, pioPartnerId, success, failed);
}
```

This is causing the following error:

> InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
>   Main+$Start$2+$.MoveNext ()

.

---

After that I've found a topic on Player.IO forum ([available here](https://gamesnet.yahoo.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=34388)) called *Utilizing Player.IO in Unity Javascript*. Suggested approach of creating delegates in JS by the author of that topic: go straight to the .Net type and declare them as `System.Delegate`.

```
var pioConnectSuccessCallback : System.Delegate;

function success(client : Client) {
  //function content
}

function Start () {
  pioConnectSuccessCallback = System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(PlayerIOClient.Callback.<PlayerIOClient.Client>), this, "success");
  PlayerIOClient.PlayerIO.Connect(pioGameId, pioConnectionId, pioUserId, pioAuth, pioPartnerId, pioConnectSuccessCallback, pioConnectErrorCallback);
}
```

This is unfortunately also not working for me, although the guys on the forum present it as a working solution (but it may be outdated).

The error I'm getting:

> Assets/Main.js(51,35): BCE0023: No appropriate version of
>   'PlayerIOClient.PlayerIO.Connect' for the argument list '(String,
>   String, String, String, String, System.Delegate, System.Delegate)' was
>   found.

So it seems like Connect method doesn't like `System.Delegate` as a parameter or those were not initialized well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3rd way is working, the function is expecting 8 parameters and that was why it didn't work for me.